# How to provide multiple addresses to the $DOCKER_VOLUMES variable in the docker-compose file for a gitlab-runner service

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

according to the gitlab-runner document; In order to have access to a specific volume inside the executor container, you can add the following option to it when registering a runner:

> --docker-volumes value
>
> > Bind-mount a volume and create it if it doesn't exist prior to mounting. Can be specified multiple times once per mountpoint, e.g. --docker-volumes 'test0:/test0' --docker-volumes 'test1:/test1' or use $DOCKER_VOLUMES as the environment variable.

Now the question is, if we want to Bind-mount multiple volumes through the $DOCKER_VOLUMES environment variable, how should we use it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest solution I've found. Specify the volumes in a template config and pass that to the register command:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#runners-configuration-template-file

```
cat > /etc/gitlab-runner/test-config.template.toml << EOF
[[runners]]
  [runners.docker]
    volumes=["/path/to/file:/path/to/file","/path/to/file2:/path/to/file2:ro", "/cache"]
EOF

gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --template-config /etc/gitlab-runner/test-config.template.toml
```